# REST API to manage ftp accounts on server

Tags: php, node.js, api, rest, ftp

I need to seek or develop an API to manage ftp accounts on a server using PHP/nodeJS/anything.

Are you aware of a library that helps managing ftp users or a software I could deploy on a server that fits that kind of need ?

Comment: `I need to develop` seems to be in conflict with `Are you aware of a Library` would you not say?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is isp config https://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig/online-demo/ you can manage many things among which ftp accounts it's free and open source.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks a bit overkill for my uses but I look into it